# jQuery show not working after added a new element in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am loading elements into a div container using Ajax / Request.  By default I'm hiding an input box. If a user clicks an edit icon on that div, I want to show the input box. Here is my code:

**HTML CODE**

```
    <div class='container'>
      <input type = 'text' onkeydown='saveFn(event,this)' name = 'editemail' class = 'editemail' style='display:none;     height:20px;' />
    </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
 $(".container").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).find(".editemail").show()); //Note it works fine If i didn't load any new elements into the div.
 });
```

Console Log Output before loading new element into the container.

```
   <input type="text" onkeydown="saveFn(event,this)" name="editemail" class="editemail" style="height: 20px; " value="hyther@zohocorp.com" title="press enter to save">
```

Console Log Output after loading an element into the container.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="saveFn(event,this)" name="editemail" class="editemail" style="height: 20px; display: none; " value="saravanan@zohocorp.com" title="press enter to save">
```

Even though I am also tried to remove the "style" attribute from this element and adding a new style element, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

First you should read the jQuery Docs FAQ section: [Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F)

Use on() to delegate the handler for future elements

```
$(document).on('click', ".container", function(){
/* your code*/
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('click','.container',function(){
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried the same as you told but the response is same . I am loading contents via Ajax . 
    `code`             

       $(document).on('click','container',function(){
                        $(this).find(".editemail").show();
       });

Output :
      Method calls but the output is same . Why ?

Comment: not `'container'`, `'.container'` -- you need the `.` to indicate it's a class.

Comment: Sorry typo mistake. Click event already works on my function but the "$(this).find(".editemail").show()" is not working .

Answer (score 1):

Try this one instead:

```
$('.container').live('click', function(){
     /* Your Code Here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `click()` bound is getting lost after an ajax request. In `JQuery` you can use `.live()` function to get this working however this function is now deprecated and they encourage you to use `.on()` or `.delegate()`. Personally i've have tons of headecks using `.on()` and `.delegate()` and rather use the plugin `livequery`. With livequery plugin is as simple as:

```
 $(function(){

    $('#elementId').livequery('click',function(){
       //do something on click
    }) 
 });
```

For more information go to:
[.livequery()](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)
[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)